# Query timing out, but looks right

Tags: marketing-cloud, query, sql

Why isn't this working? I took this query

```
SELECT s.TriggeredSendCustomerKey as TriggeredSend,
COUNT(o.TriggeredSendCustomerKey) as TotalOpens,
COUNT(case when o.IsUnique = 1 then 1 end) as UniqueOpens
FROM _Sent s with (NOLOCK)
JOIN _Open o with (NOLOCK)
ON s.SubscriberKey = o.SubscriberKey
WHERE s.EventDate BETWEEN '2017-08-01 00:00:00' AND '2017-08-31 23:59:59'
AND s.TriggeredSendCustomerKey IN ('40712')
AND o.TriggeredSendCustomerKey IN ('40712')
Group by s.TriggeredSendCustomerKey
```

Which works for one triggered send perfectly. Whenever I add more TriggeredSendCustomerKeys in the parenthesis, the numbers are off. I also don't like hard coding the number so I tried this, which validates and seems like it should work, but the system doesn't like it.

```
SELECT s.TriggeredSendCustomerKey as TriggeredSend,
COUNT(o.TriggeredSendCustomerKey) as TotalOpens,
COUNT(case when o.IsUnique = 1 then 1 end) as UniqueOpens
FROM _Sent s with (NOLOCK)
JOIN _Open o with (NOLOCK)
ON s.SubscriberKey = o.SubscriberKey
WHERE s.EventDate BETWEEN '2017-08-01 00:00:00' AND '2017-08-31 23:59:59'
AND s.TriggeredSendCustomerKey = o.TriggeredSendCustomerKey
Group by s.TriggeredSendCustomerKey
```

Comment: Here's what I ended up doing in the end. I broke it up into two queries as data kid suggested. The query I posted where s.TriggeredSendCustomerKey = o.TriggeredSendCustomerKey finally worked when I first created a subset of the _Sent table and instead queried on that. Adam's answer was great too, but I gave the "right" answer to DataKid because he was first to act. Thanks all!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `s.TriggeredSendCustomerKey = o.TriggeredSendCustomerKey` is way more computationally expensive than

```
AND s.TriggeredSendCustomerKey IN ('40712')
AND o.TriggeredSendCustomerKey IN ('40712')
```

Although the hard coding reducing flexibility, it limits the range of values that the system has to search.

Instead of just searching for `40712`, it has to return every case where the two value are the same. That combined with running joins on a system table, and you have a query that is taking longer than 30 minutes and timing out.

To improve performance I would break it into 2 part.

1. **The query without the Aggregate Functions(TableA)**

   ```
   SELECT s.TriggeredSendCustomerKey as TriggeredSend
   ,o.TriggeredSendCustomerKey as Opens
   ,(case when o.IsUnique = 1 then 1 end) as IsUnique
   FROM _Sent s with (NOLOCK)
   JOIN _Open o with (NOLOCK)
   ON s.SubscriberKey = o.SubscriberKey
   WHERE s.EventDate BETWEEN '2017-08-01 00:00:00' AND '2017-08-31 23:59:59'
   AND s.TriggeredSendCustomerKey = o.TriggeredSendCustomerKey
   ```
2. **Query with Aggregates (TableB)**:

   ```
   SELECT TriggeredSend,
   COUNT(Opens) as TotalOpens,
   COUNT(IsUnique) as UniqueOpens
   FROM [TableA]
   GROUP BY TriggeredSend
   ```

Comment: Well that explains why it's timing out, but can you help me make it better so that I can do a lookup?

Comment: Staging tables? will update my answer

Comment: `40712` is that an exact match or is the entire number longer?

Comment: it is exact match

Comment: Then you could use "=" instead of in. Alot quicker and should give you the right numbers

Comment: Another reason i didn't like the hard coding was because it was skewing the results. I think there must have been duplicate subscriber keys. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3):

I agree with [**@Data_Kid**](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/users/31726/data-kid) about breaking it up into two queries. Generally speaking, I try not to join multiple [**System Data Views**](http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/automation_studio/using_automation_studio_activities/using_the_query_activity/data_views/) in a single query -- simply because you're asking for a timeout if you have a high send volume.  Here's how I'd approach it.

The first query selects only `_Sent` rows and does an overwrite on the target:

```
select distinct
s.TriggeredSendCustomerKey as TriggeredSend
FROM _Sent s
where 
s.EventDate >= '2017-08-01 00:00:00' 
and s.EventDate <= '2017-08-31 23:59:59'
and s.TriggeredSendCustomerKey IN ('40712','40713','40714')
/* name: TriggeredSendSummary_Sends */
/* target: TriggeredSendSummary */
/* action: overwrite */
```

The second query uses the results of the first query and inner joins with `_Open` and does an update:

```
select 
s.TriggeredSendCustomerKey as TriggeredSend
, COUNT(o.TriggeredSendCustomerKey) as TotalOpens
, COUNT(case when o.IsUnique = 1 then 1 else 0 end) as UniqueOpens
from TriggeredSendSummary s
inner JOIN _Open o ON o.SubscriberKey = s.SubscriberKey
group by s.TriggeredSendCustomerKey
/* name: TriggeredSendSummary_Opens */
/* target: TriggeredSendSummary */
/* action: update */
```